Moisture or heat damaged luxury vinyl planks
So yeah these cali longboards were wrapped in plastic to protect them and clearly moisture got in because half of them have like a white washed stain on them. I'm assuming they can't be fixed but was wondering if anyone ever restored the color or got rid of the stain? It's kind of like white like when you set a hot pot on a wooden table and the only way to get it out is with a steam iron on a towel. Anyone ever save a vinyl plank from this cloudy white stain?

Please provide a photo.

True vinyl planks are extremely resistant to moisture and will not show any ill effects from it. ( To prove it I placed a 12" piece of LVP in a bucket of water for a week. Nothing happened to it.)
What you may have is a laminate flooring that is manufactured with a masonite wood core.  The wood can absorb moisture and show as discoloration through to the surface of the product.  In that case the flooring is most likely ruined.
